mlir-opt does not recognize dialect tensor
I built MLIR by following the original instructions and completed the Toy tutorial to familiarize myself with the basics. While working through the tutorial, I attempted to add the tensor and linalg dialects to the context registry to use the toy-opt tool for lowering code like the following:

  func.func @main() {
    %static_tensor = tensor.empty() : tensor<4x8xf32>
    return
  }


The goal was to test whether the tensor and linalg dialects were available. However, I consistently encountered errors such as:
loc("./test/Engine/tensorLinalg.mlir":11:35): error: expected ':'
Error can't load file ./test/Engine/tensorLinalg.mlir
lli: Symbols not found: [ main ]

To troubleshoot further, I tried using mlir-opt from the MLIR repository inside the LLVM project. However, it seems that the dialects listed on the MLIR page (MLIR Dialects Documentation) are not registered by default. For example:
test_llvm.mlir:3:10: error: Dialect `tensor' not found for custom op 'tensor.empty' 
    %0 = tensor.empty() : tensor<4x8xf32>
         ^
test_llvm.mlir:3:10: note: Registered dialects: acc, amx, arm_neon, arm_sme, arm_sve, builtin, dlti, func, gpu, llvm, nvvm, omp, rocdl, spirv, vcix, x86vector ; for more info on dialect registration see https://mlir.llvm.org/getting_started/Faq/#registered-loaded-dependent-whats-up-with-dialects-management

Currently, I only wish to use the arith, memref, linalg, and tensor dialects. Among these, I can already use arith and memref and lower them to LLVM IR. However, I am unsure how to register and use the tensor and linalg dialects effectively.
Is there an existing project or setup that could help with the boilerplate for this process? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
